# Select, copy, delete multiple files and create a word document table of content with hyperlink files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox (listbox1), I want to select multiple files and copy those files to another folder (Destination folder). Then the listbox will show the data such as file name and filepath of all selected files in the Destination folder.

- In Listbox I can choose files and delete them in the Destination folder.
  The way i do so far: I save the file path in workbook's cell and add them in listbox. Then try to copy those files from their path saved in cell to Destination folder but it didn't work

The code i use:

```
Dim FSO 
'Create Object Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String
Dim sFile, oFile, sh As Worksheet, K&
Set sh = Sheet2
sh.Range("A:A").ClearContents
sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select files", MultiSelect:=True)
If VarType(sFile) = vbBoolean Then MsgBox ("No file selected"): Exit Sub
For Each oFile In sFile
    K = K + 1
    sh.Cells(K, 1).Value = oFile
Next
'Change to match the source folder path
sSFolder = oFile
'Change to match the destination folder path
sDFolder = "E:\" & Sheet2.Range("B1").Value & "\" & Sheet2.Range("B2").Value
sFile.CopyFile sSFolder, sDFolder, True
End Sub
```

- Finally, create a word file with Destination folder name and filename with hyperlink (filepath), like this:

[image]

[image]

Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad english

Here is code i'm trying to create word file

```
Option Explicit
Sub InsertHyperLink()
Dim aWord As Object
Dim wDoc As Object
Dim i&, EndR&
Dim Rng As Range

Set aWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wDoc = aWord.Documents.Add
EndR = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To EndR
    
    wDoc.Range.InsertAfter Cells(i, 1) & vbCrLf
    wDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf
    wDoc.Paragraphs(wDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wDoc.Paragraphs(wDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range, _
    Address:=Cells(i, 3), TextToDisplay:=Left(Cells(i, 2), InStr(1, Cells(i, 2), ".") - 1)
    wDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf
    wDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf
Next
    aWord.Visible = True

aWord.Activate  
Set wDoc = Nothing
Set aWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

But with this code, the file in the same folder is not with Folder name:
Folder 1
File 1
Folder 2
File 2....
Folder 1
File 5

Comment: What code do have so far? What is your question? Where do you run in troubles?

Comment: Oh sorry, i've edited my questions